# Backbone.js Mobile Slider - Passing Variable through View Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, mobile-website

I'm following this tutorial to build a mobile slider: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/

The only difference is, I'm trying to incorporate it into Backbone.  However, I've run into a variable problem.  Can anyone offer some advice as to how to get this to work.  Passing these variables throughout the View's functions is the problem:

```
var sliding = startClientX = startPixelOffset = pixelOffset = currentSlide = 0,
slideCount = $('.slide').length;
```

**Full Backbone View:**

```
WhiteDeals.Views.EditorView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'slideStart', 'slide');

    var sliding = startClientX = startPixelOffset = pixelOffset = currentSlide = 0,
    slideCount = $('#dealSlide').length;

},

events: {
    "touchstart"             : "slideStart",
    "mousedown"              : "slideStart",
    "mouseup"                : "slideEnd",
    "touchend"               : "slideEnd",
    "mousemove"              : "slide",
    "touchmove"              : "slide"
},

slideStart: function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.touches)
      event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
    if (sliding == 0) {
      sliding = 1;
      startClientX = event.clientX;
    }
}, // End slideStart

slide: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.originalEvent.touches)
        event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
        var deltaSlide = event.clientX - startClientX;

    if (sliding == 1 && deltaSlide != 0) {
      sliding = 2;
      startPixelOffset = pixelOffset;
    }

    if (sliding == 2) {
      var touchPixelRatio = 1;
      if ((currentSlide == 0 && event.clientX > startClientX) ||
          (currentSlide == slideCount - 1 && event.clientX < startClientX))
        touchPixelRatio = 3;
      pixelOffset = startPixelOffset + deltaSlide / touchPixelRatio;
      $('#dealSlider').css('transform', 'translate3d(' + pixelOffset + 'px,0,0)').removeClass();
    }
},

slideEnd: function(event) {
    if (sliding == 2) {
        sliding = 0;
        currentSlide = pixelOffset < startPixelOffset ? currentSlide + 1 : currentSlide - 1;
        currentSlide = Math.min(Math.max(currentSlide, 0), slideCount - 1);
        pixelOffset = currentSlide * -$('body').width();
        $('#temp').remove();
        $('<style id="temp">#dealSlider.animate{transform:translate3d(' + pixelOffset + 'px,0,0)}</style>').appendTo('head');
        $('#dealSlider').addClass('animate').css('transform', '');
    }
}, // End slideEnd

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(JST['editor/view']());
    return this;
}

}); // End of Views EditorView
```

Comment: A possible solution might be to just keep the touchstart event and function in the eventdelegator.  Then add event listeners for touchmove and touchstop within the touchstart's function as well as all of the subfunctions.

Comment: FYI – For people looking to add a great mobile touch slider to backbone, I ended up going with Swipe.js.  It was easy to set-up and has great performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pack those variable into a model, like:

```
var CoordsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({})
var coord = new CoordsModel();
```

then pass it to the `WhiteDeals` view:

```
var view = new WhiteDeals({model: coord});
```

then accros all functions, through models' getters/setter I have access to its variables, for example:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'slideStart', 'slide');

    // var sliding = startClientX = startPixelOffset = pixelOffset = currentSlide = 0

    this.model.set('sliding', 0);
    this.model.set('startClientX', 0);
    ...
    this.model.set('currentSlide', 0);

    slideCount = $('#dealSlide').length;

},
...
slideStart: function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.touches)
        event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
    if (sliding == 0) {
        // sliding = 1;
        // startClientX = event.clientX;
        this.model.set('sliding', 1);
        this.model.set('startClientX', event.clientX);
    }
}, // End slideStart
```